# Replication, sharding and some general guidance

Tags: ravendb

First some background on the questions. I have never used ravedb before and I'm evaluating it for an upcoming project. The project is very document centric and seems like a great fit so far in my "quick and dirty" test project.

The app itself has very little data, SQLite on a 486 would probably suffice for our database needs. It does have a lot of large image data though, and we would be using ravendb for image storing and as as an image cache. So here's a few questions:

1. Each document can be used by one or more divisions. We store a list of divisions (ints) on each document and query against it. Is this considered best practice or should this information be in metadata?
2. We will need to make use of replication and sharding. As our data is small I was thinking of replicating all of it to various shards and only sharding on the image data, is this possible?
3. Is it possible to store data in more than one shard? If a document was accessible be Divisions 1,2 and 3 and our sharding was that granular we would like to push the document to the shard the user will be accessing for everything else.
4. Does sharding work just as easily with attachments?
5. I mentioned we would store cached image data (resized images etc). Is it advisable that this be put into a separate database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flukus,
Sharding does NOT work for attachments.
You can mix & match replication and sharding, but usually we treat them separately. One database for the sharded data, one database for the replicated data on all the nodes.

Comment: I like the idea of multiple databases, that simplifies things a lot. If sharding doesn't work on attachments then should I store the image data as a normal document?